# LibTorch, convert deeplabv3_resnet101 to c++

Tags: pytorch, libtorch

I am trying to use this example code from the PyTorch [website](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html) to convert a python model for use in the PyTorch c++ api (LibTorch).

```
Converting to Torch Script via Tracing
To convert a PyTorch model to Torch Script via tracing, you must pass an instance of your model along with an example input to the torch.jit.trace function. This will produce a torch.jit.ScriptModule object with the trace of your model evaluation embedded in the module’s forward method:

import torch
import torchvision

# An instance of your model.
model = torchvision.models.resnet18()

# An example input you would normally provide to your model's forward() method.
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)

# Use torch.jit.trace to generate a torch.jit.ScriptModule via tracing.
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
traced_script_module.save("model.pt")
```

This example works fine, and saves out the file as expected. 
When i switch to this model:

`model = models.segmentation.deeplabv3_resnet101(pretrained=True)`

It gives me the following error:

```
File "convert.py", line 14, in <module>
    traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\__init__.py", line 636, in trace
          raise ValueError('Expected more than 1 value per channel when training, got input size {}'.format(size))
ValueError: Expected more than 1 value per channel when training, got input size torch.Size([1, 256, 1, 1])
```

I assume this is because the `example` format is wrong, but how can I get the correct one?

Based on the comments below, my new code is:

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import models


model = models.segmentation.deeplabv3_resnet101(pretrained=True)
model.eval()


# An example input you would normally provide to your model's forward() method.
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)

# Use torch.jit.trace to generate a torch.jit.ScriptModule via tracing.
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)

traced_script_module.save("model.pt")
```

And i now get the error:

```
File "convert.py", line 15, in <module>
    traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\__init__.py", line 636, in trace
    var_lookup_fn, _force_outplace)
RuntimeError: Only tensors and (possibly nested) tuples of tensors are supported as inputs or outputs of traced functions (toIValue at C:\a\w\1\s\windows\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/pybind_utils.h:91)
(no backtrace available)
```

Comment: Are you sure your example size has more than one channel and you are passing the sample shape as `example` in your code?

Comment: I am not sure of that! How do I know what to pass as example? Thanks!

Comment: Use the same shape `(1, 3, 224, 224)`

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. Does 'deeplabv3_resnet101' have a different shape? How can I find out what it is? Thank you for your time.

Comment: By checking the model or reading about it. Still you should provide input shape of the images you will put through the network.

Comment: https://pytorch.org/hub/pytorch_vision_deeplabv3_resnet101/ says 'All pre-trained models expect input images normalized in the same way, i.e. mini-batches of 3-channel RGB images of shape (N, 3, H, W), where N is the number of images, H and Ware expected to be at least 224 pixels. The images have to be loaded in to a range of [0, 1] and then normalized using mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406] and std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225].'.  So my example would be' shape (N, 3, H, W),'? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

(from pytorch forums)

trace only supports modules that have tensor or tuple of tensor as output.
According to deeplabv3 implementation, its output is OrderedDict. That is a problem.
To solve this, make a wrapper module

```
class wrapper(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(wrapper, self).__init__()
        self.model = model

    def forward(self, input):
        results = []
        output = self.model(input)
        for k, v in output.items():
            results.append(v)
        return tuple(results)

model = wrapper(deeplap_model)
#trace...
```

Has my model saving out.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem originates in the BatchNorm layer. If it requires *more than one value per channel*, then your model is in training mode. Could you invoke https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/classtorch_1_1nn_1_1_module.html#_CPPv4N5torch2nn6Module4evalEv on the model and see if there's an improvement?

Otherwise you could also try to generate random data with more than one instance in a batch, i.e. `example = torch.rand(5, 3, 224, 224)`.

Furthermore, you should take care to properly normalise your data, however, this isn't causing the error here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. i have added:  `model = models.segmentation.deeplabv3_resnet101(pretrained=True)
model.eval()` and used the `example = torch.rand(5, 3, 224, 224)`, and I now get: 

`RuntimeError: Only tensors and (possibly nested) tuples of tensors are supported as inputs or outputs of traced functions (toIValue at C:\a\w\1\s\windows\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/pybind_utils.h:91)
(no backtrace available)`

Comment: @anti Could you try either one? I.e. either set model to evaluation mode or try with `torch.rand(5, 3, 224, 224)`. The evaluation mode is supposed to solve the problem.

Comment: Same result both ways. ` Only tensors and (possibly nested) tuples of tensors are supported as inputs or outputs of traced functions (toIValue at C:\a\w\1\s\windows\pytorch\torch/csrc/jit/pybind_utils.h:91)`